# API PLATFORM custom identifier in parent class/table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have entities that make use of Inheritance Mapping Doctrine inheritance. I have a custom identifier that I generate with @ORM\PrePersist(), which is in a trait and this is used in the parent class.

I want to be able to update properties that the child class has, for this reason, I need to run endpoints on the child entity

When I run an item operation, api platform can't find the resource.

`PATCH /api/childas/{hash}`

NotFoundHttpException
`Not Found`

api platform, it doesn't recognize hash as identifier. Take the id as your identified, even if it is false and hash is true.

Trait to generate hashes with which I identify the resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait HashableTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $hash;

    public function getHash(): ?string
    {
        return $this->hash;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function setHash()
    {
        $this->hash = \sha1(\random_bytes(10));
    }
}
```

Parent class, is the table where the hash will be stored

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\HashableTrait;

/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *  1 = "App\Entity\ChildA",
 *  2 = "App\Entity\ChildB"
 * })
 */
class Parent
{
    use HashableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // Properties, setters, getters
}
```

Child class, on which I want to perform operations, such as updating some property that belongs to this class

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


class ChildA extends Parent
{
   // Custom properties for ChildA
}
```

Config api platform operations for entity Child

```
App\Entity\ChildA:
    collectionOperations:
        post: ~
    itemOperations:
        post: ~
        get: ~
        patch: ~
        delete: ~
```

I have thought about using data providers, but I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error was because both the `hash` property in the trait and the `id` property in the parent entity must be accessible from the entity to use.

Doctrine ORM uses reflection class to get information about attributes and their annotations. `ReflectionClass::hasProperty` obviously does not allow viewing private properties in the parent class.